# How to make headers in .csv relevant to attributes in WEKA

Tags: weka

I have just started using WEKA and get some problems with file converting
Below I have a test table in .csv
The problem is that I need 4 attributes (4 columns): arr/number/airport/code.But WEKA recognise the table as one united column, so it is impossible to analyze it.

Arr number  airport code
departure   221 SVO VQBOQ
departure   222 SLY VQBOE
departure   223 AER VQBOT
arrival 224 SLY VQBOT
departure   225 DME VQBOU
departure   226 SLY VQBOM

How to adjust the headers to get separate columns in WEKA?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would like to recommend you to also ask this question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/, as your question is not strictly about software development

Answer (score 0):

Convert the .csv file back into excel(.xlsx) or open office(.odt/.calc). Then, in the Excel sheet, make sure the first row is denoting the different attributes (no similarly named attributes are allowed) where the very last column is the class labels. After this stage, save the Excel sheet as .csv and make sure to choose text delimiter as shown in this figure:
 [image]

Everything should work now.